# Python Selenium Proxy doesn't change IP address

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

I'm trying to change my IP address in order to bypass crawl social data using this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

if __name__ == '__main__':
    chromedriver_path = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'
    window_size = "1920,1080"
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=%s" % window_size)
  
    random_proxy = '124.240.187.80:82'
    webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['proxy'] = {
        "httpProxy": random_proxy,
        "ftpProxy": random_proxy,
        "sslProxy": random_proxy,
        "proxyType": "MANUAL"
    }
   
    webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['acceptSslCerts'] = True

    chromedriver = webdriver.Chrome(
        executable_path=chromedriver_path,
        options=chrome_options
    )

    chromedriver.get('https://whatismyip.com')
```

But it doesn't works. My IP address remain the same. Any sugesstion?
Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ChromeOptions` instead of Chrome capabilities

```py
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={random_proxy}')
```

Comment: it's doesn't work. WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED